# Sequentially updating a pandas column from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have one big dateframe in which I need to create a column and feed it with data from other dataframes. I searched and I found similar problems but could not adapt them successfully to my situation. Here is what needs to be done (small example):

**What I have now:**

```
data_all_preliminary=
Date    Type   Col1    Col2
1       a      x       x
2       a      x       x
3       a      x       x
4       a      x       x
1       b      y       y
2       b      y       y
3       b      y       y
4       b      y       y
5       b      y       y

data_type_a=
Date    Type   Value
1       a      a1 
2       a      a2 
3       a      a3 
4       a      a4 
5       a      a5 

data_type_b=
Date    Type   Value
1       b      b1 
2       b      b2 
3       b      b3 
4       b      b4 
5       b      b5
```

**What I want to have:**

```
data_all_final=
Date    Type   Col1    Col2    Value
1       a      x       x       a1
2       a      x       x       a2
3       a      x       x       a3
4       a      x       x       a4
1       b      y       y       b1
2       b      y       y       b2
3       b      y       y       b3
4       b      y       y       b4
5       b      y       y       b5
```

I have many of the source dataframes (not just a and b) and I want to write a loop to go through all of them and fill out the original dataframe on the appropriate dates. I also need to keep the existing Col1 and Col2 as they are

I did this with merge but I every time I was creating a new column with values in the original dataframe and not updating the single "values" one.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

append the datatype dataframes and join with first one.

```py
data_type_df = data_type_a.append(data_type_b)
data_all_preliminary.merge(data_type_df, how='left', on=['Date', 'Type'])
```

which gives you the following results.

```
   Date Type Col1 Col2 Value
0     1    a    x    x    a1
1     2    a    x    x    a2
2     3    a    x    x    a3
3     4    a    x    x    a4
4     1    b    y    y    b1
5     2    b    y    y    b2
6     3    b    y    y    b3
7     4    b    y    y    b4
8     5    b    y    y    b5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `merge` and `append`:

```
>>> data_all_preliminary.merge(data_type_a).append(data_all_preliminary.merge(data_type_b))
```

**Output**

```
   Date Type Col1 Col2 Value
0     1    a    x    x    a1
1     2    a    x    x    a2
2     3    a    x    x    a3
3     4    a    x    x    a4
0     1    b    y    y    b1
1     2    b    y    y    b2
2     3    b    y    y    b3
3     4    b    y    y    b4
4     5    b    y    y    b5
```